# Comparing with EVERY distinct value listed in another table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following two tables

Table: **Customer**

```
Cust_ID    FName
-------    -----
1          X
2          Y
3          Z
```

Table: **Account**

```
Acct_Number    Cust_ID    Acct_Type
-----------    -------    ---------
1001           1          savings
1002           1          capital
1003           2          savings
1004           2          capital
1005           2          vip
1006           3          capital
1007           3          vip
```

There are three different types of account in Account table, (savings, capital and vip), I want to **find the customer who have an account of every type which is listed in Account relation**(without using any aggregate operator).That is, in this case, Y will qualify, as he is the only one who has all types of account.

I got a suggestion to try the following, which is not working:

```
SELECT c.FName, c.Cust_ID FROM Customer AS c
JOIN Account AS a1 ON c.Cust_ID = a1.Cust_ID
JOIN Account AS a2 ON c.Cust_ID = a2.Cust_ID
WHERE a1.Acct_Type <> a2.Acct_Type;
```

The above query is giving the customer who has account in two distinct type, not all. Helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: No aggregate functions, eh?  Why ever not? I have to go to New York City. My car has a flat tire. I don't want to repair it. What's the best way to New York if I'm driving on my rims?

Comment: And there's no table listing all possible account types? Smells bad.

Comment: @Cylindric The above mentioned problem is related to a database course that I am taking, the main idea behind the problem is to practice the set theories, relational algebra and domain calculus, i guess thats why the solution has to be kept non-aggregated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a query using `not exists`

```
select c.* from customer c
where not exists (
    select acct_type from account a2
    where acct_type not in (
        select distinct acct_type
        from account a3 where a3.Cust_ID = c.Cust_ID
    )
)
```

Comment: @rubiksKube updated answer to use not exists instead of count

Comment: simply great, now trying to understand the solution. Thanks

Comment: @rubiksKube the query translates select all customers where an account type from the account tables that the customer does not have does not exist (in other words, the customer has all types of accounts)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is relational division:

```
forall x:p(x)
```

but this is not possible to express in sql so you have to rewrite it to:

```
not exists x : not p(x)
```

in other words, for which customers does it not exists an accounttype such that the account does not have it. Something like:

```
SELECT c.FName, c.Cust_ID 
FROM Customer AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select distinct Acct_Type 
    from Account t
    where not exists (
        select 1 from Account as a
        where a.cust_id = c.cust_id
          and a.Acct_Type = t. Acct_Type
    )
);
```

Edit: did not notice that aggregates was disallowed

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If the `Acct_Type` values are not previously known, the following query can be used to get the desired results. Obviously, it is much more tedious than using aggregation operations.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        all_combinations.Cust_ID
    FROM Account Acct
    RIGHT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            c.Cust_ID,
            a.Acct_Type
        FROM Customer AS c
        CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT Acct_Type FROM Account) AS a
    ) all_combinations
    ON Acct.Cust_ID = all_combinations.Cust_ID AND Acct.Acct_Type = all_combinations.Acct_Type
    WHERE Acct.Cust_ID IS NOT NULL
) all_acct_types
ON c.Cust_ID = all_acct_types.Cust_ID;
```

Comment: account of EVERY type - would mean that the user has no knowledge of the account type or number of distinct account.

Comment: Please see modified answer above, which handles previously unknown values of Acct_Type.